# C# через objectArx в AutoCad

Tags: c#, autocad

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какую-нибудь документацию для создания c# библиотеки для автокада.

Интересует управление видом чертежа (сверху/спереди),
Управление командами(например есть проблема с вызовом

```
AcadApp.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.SendStringToExecute("_ERASE _ALL ",false, false, true);))
```

Answer (score 1):

Мне нравится больше командный метод а-ля `AutoLisp`
попробуй:

```
class myUtils
{
    /* ads_queueexpr for Acad version < 2012 " - acad.exe" */
    [DllImport("accore.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,
        EntryPoint = "ads_queueexpr")]
    extern static private int ads_queueexpr(byte[] command);

    [CommandMethod("ea")]
    public void testErase()
    {

        var doc = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        var ed = doc.Editor;
        var db = doc.Database;
        var trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();
        using (trans)
        {
            System.Text.UnicodeEncoding unEncode = new System.Text.UnicodeEncoding();
            ads_queueexpr(unEncode.GetBytes("(COMMAND \"_.ERASE\" \"_All\" \"\")"));
            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```